Expo React Native ScrollView not working on React Native Web but it is on mobile
I am creating a project using react native & react native for web to take advantage of a singular code base for mobile apps and website.
I am struggling with ScrollView. It appears to be scrolling properly on mobile but not on web. I have created some dummy demo code to show this error. I have tried playing around with the flex but it still doesn't seem to work.
// App.js
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import TestScreen from './screens/TestScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
return (
 <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
   <NavigationContainer>
     <StatusBar style="auto"/>
     <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
       <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaView>);}

// Test.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 2</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 3</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 4</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 5</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Box 6</Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>);}

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    box: {
      height: 200,
      margin: 20,
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
});


ScrollView must have a bounded height: either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height (e.g., apply { flex: 1} down the view stack).

So, in my example, what should I apply flex: 1 to?

It's due to the default behavior of createStackNavigator(), if it's not required then you can choose createNativeStackNavigator(), or else if you have to use createStackNavigator() then you can fix this by making some changes in your screen declaration code.

add cardStyle: { flex: 1 } this will fix your problem

add this in the Navigator screenOptions to apply on all screens or add on specific screens, it depends on you.
    import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

    import TestScreen from './screens/TestScreen';

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
              cardStyle: {
                flex: 1
              }
            }}>
              <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>);
    }


other solution

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


Official docs, just for reference if you want to know more about this.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#cardstyle

